# Curl Upload not working for ge.tt API

Tags: php, curl

Hi i am trying to upload using this tutorial http://ge.tt/developers/start .On step 4 they mention something like this

```
 curl --upload-file myfile.txt http://blobs.ge.tt/a1b2c3/myfile.txt?sig=-TR2k2-3kjsh9nfmn4
```

What is the equivalent php code for the above line ? i tried below code , but its not working (returning bool false)

```
$url = $arr["posturl"];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$postData = array(
    'file' => '@/home/nextgen/public_html/api/myfile.txt',
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($response);
```

note : i got correct $url and myfile.txt exists and i tried replacing 'file' => '@/home/nextgen/public_html/api/myfile.txt' with '@myfile.txt' ..nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. '@myfile.txt' must be '@/full/path/to/myfile.txt'
2. curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1); is required

Answer (score 0):

If you'd used curl's -[-libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--libcurl) option you would've seen the difference. Your command line does PUT, your PHP version does multipart formpost...

Comment: What do you mean ? its like greek and latin..can you explain little bit further